# WebGL textures not working on some textures

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am trying to follow a tutorial on WebGL and I am getting weird behavior with textures. I use this code to create the texture:

```
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, document.getElementById("img"));
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

I have an image in the html file that looks like this:

```
<img id="img" src="texture.png" width="0" height="0"></img>
```

Here everything is working. I have seen a way to load images in JS only that looks like this:

```
function loadFileAsIMG(filename) {
  var result = new Image();
  result.src = filename;
  return result;
}
```

Adding the loaded image to HTML is working as it should. But somehow using this loaded image in the `gl.texImage2D` function doesn't work at all and produces this error message:

```
[Error] WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: invalid image
    texImage2D
    run (glmain.js:149)
    init (glmain.js:26)
    onload (index.html:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are loaded asynchronously over the network, you have to wait for them to load before using them

```
function loadFileAsIMG(filename, callback) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => callback(img);
  img.src = filename;
}

function funcToCallAfterImageLoads(img) {
  ...
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
  ...
}

loadFileAsIMG('url/for/some/image', funcToCallAfterImageLoads);
```

See [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)

You can also make an image loader that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and then use [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to `await` on the image being loaded

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function main() {
  const img = await loadImage('url/to/image');
  ...
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
  ...
}

main();
```

Also see [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is working now, could this also explain why I sometimes got strange results when loading shaders?